# Ruby on Rails 3 Beta: On ajax get request, I can't respond back with the html.erb view. Is there a work-around?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actionview, ruby-on-rails-3

I have began playing with Rails 3 beta and I am trying to do my usual starter project. I create a simple list of projects, but use ajax requests for the app's navigation. In Rails 3, my usual code does not work for the basic scaffold, I receive an

```
ActionView:MissingTemplate (Missing template projects/new with {:format=>[:js]}
```

Here is my a snippit from my projects controller:

```
  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.xml
  def new
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
    end
  end
```

Notice the format.js line. I use the Mootools library for my javascript and I have not yet tried out the new unobtursive hooks that rails 3 provides, so I still write it by hand. Here is the javascript request that fires when the 'new' link is clicked on the page. In Mootools, the Request.HTML update attributes updates the div I have in the HTML with the id 'main'.

```
a.addEvents({
    'click': function(e) {
        e.stop();
        console.log("Click for '" + a.get('href') + "'");

        new Request.HTML({
            url: a.get('href'),
            method: 'get',
            update: 'main',
            onRequest: function() {},
            onSuccess: function() {},
            onFailure: function(xhr) {},
            onComplete: function() {}
        }).send();
    }
});
```

So what is happening when the link is clicked, is the controller tries to respond to the js call with the new.js.erb file, which I don't have. In previous versions of rails, this would not be the case and it would respond back with the new.html.erb automatically. If I remove the format.js line in the controller, it responds back, but I don't want the response to have layout when called through javascript.

Is there something that changed in Rails 3 beta?

Answer (score 0):

It feels like everything changed in Rails 3. :)
Have you installed [the driver for Mootools](http://github.com/kevinvaldek/mootools-ujs)?